# Can't get javavws IcedTea to work (JRE OpenJDK version 8) in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, java, openjdk

I can't get javavws (IcedTea) to work (JRE OpenJDK version 8) in Ubuntu 18.04.

1. I installed IcedTea via: `sudo apt install default-jre icedtea-netx`
2. The active version of my JRE is: OpenJDK 8:

   ```
   franc@franc-XPS-13-9370:/etc$ echo $JAVA_HOME  
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
   ```
3. After trying to launch the JNLP application with `javaws knvb.jnlp` I get the error message below:

   ```
   franc@franc-XPS-13-9370:/etc$ javaws knvb.jnlp
   selected jre: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
   thread 'main' panicked at 'Error spawning JVM process, java executable: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java], arguments: 
   [["-splash:/usr/share/icedtea-web/javaws_splash.png",  
     "-Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/share/icedtea-web/javaws.jar:/usr/share/java/js.jar:/usr/share/java/tagsoup.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:",  
     "-classpath", "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:",  
     "-Dicedtea-web.bin.name=javaws", "-Dicedtea-web.bin.location=/usr/lib/icedtea-web/bin/javaws",   
     "net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot",   
     "knvb.jnlp"
   ]]',   
   src/os_access.rs:36:19
   note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the symbolic link /usr/lib/jvm/default-java to java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 (instead of the java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64)